# Prevent call-process from stealing focus

Tags: focus, call-process

When Emacs executes `call-process` after the focus has moved to another window (this is after a compilation step which takes some time to finish) it grabs the focus and causes the pointer to move to the upper-right of the Emacs frame. This is on Linux using gnome-shell.

Is there any way to disable this behavior? Either globally or on a per-call basis?

**Edit:** Found it. The frame was being explicitly set by `select-frame-set-input-focus` in a function that I was adding to `compilation-finish-function`. I should understand the code I copy-and-paste a little better.

Comment: Your question implies that you are executing `call-process` from somewhere other than Emacs.  How is it that you are executing `call-process` from another application that has focus instead of Emacs?

Comment: It's from within Emacs. It's being called at the end of a compilation process (via compilation-finish-functions) which takes enough time for me to move focus to another application. I'll fix the question.

Comment: What function, please, is attached to the variable `compilation-finish-function`?  This will vary depending upon what you are doing.  In the end, we will be looking for functions such as `select-frame-set-input-focus` and perhaps `x-focus-frame`.  Alternatives include, but are not limited to things like `(select-frame)` and/or `(raise-frame)`.